# Understanding ip route output

Tags: linux, routing, iproute

I am learning about Linux routing, routing tables, IP routing, etc...
The following is the output from `ip route` followed by the output of `route`:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp0s20f3 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.103 metric 600
```

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         pfSense.localdo 0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp0s20f3
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
```

So, what I understand from the output of route is that anything routed to my local network 192.168.1.0/24 is on the local network and so the interface is essentially unspecified. Same thing with anything sent to link-local (which I believe is my loopback device). Finally, anything that is routed to anything else is sent to the default gateway which is my router. Hopefully I've got this right.

I am having difficulty parsing the output of `ip route`. I can see what my default gateway is obviously but I have trouble matching the other two lines with the output of `route`. I've been through the documentation and learned quite a bit thankfully but haven't been able to find anything specific about the output of the command aside from the fact that it tells me the interface and the destination. If anyone could be so kind as to break down a line for me and explain how to read it I would greatly appreciate it!

Some relevant links for those who stroll upon this question once answered:

http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-route.html

http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html#ss9.5

Comment: Where do you get this notion of "null interface" from? What does that even mean? The second and third routes are connected routes meaning that that subnet can be reached via the given interface (wlp0s20f3 in this case) without an intervening router. That is, they are for the subnets that the interface is configured in.

Comment: I read that 0.0.0.0 was a special address that essentially said nowhere or unspecified. I probably could have worded that better but what I mean is that there is no intermediary device and those objects are on the local network.

Comment: Ok, in that case it sounds like you know what those routes represent. Can you clarify then what specifically you don't understand?

Comment: Specifically the stuff that follows the device. Scope link etc... And how lines of ip route can be seen in the output of route.

Answer (score 1):

> link-local (which I believe is my loopback device).

*link-local* (the `169.254.0.0/16`) is a special subnet. Loopback device is "lo" and 127.0.0.1, and `scope host` and LOOPBACK (with `ip a`)

The other two lines of `ip route show` can be created with:

```
ip address add 192.168.0.16/24 dev eth0
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
```

This gives the same as this (dhcp), just the address is different (15 vs 16):

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.15 metric 202 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.15 metric 202
```

---

> Some relevant links for those who stroll upon this question once
>   answered

???