# How Do You Set A Default Route 0.0.0.0/0 On A DHCP Enabled Interface

Tags: routing

I'm running `Debian Bullseye v 11`  and I'm trying to set a default route `0.0.0.0/0` for Internet access on a *DHCP* enabled interface `eth0`.

Interface `eth0` is getting an IP address from the ISP and interface `eth1` is *DHCP* assigning addresses to clients. I need clients to be able to access the internet.

I've tried various configurations I saw online like `route add 0.0.0.0/0 gw {hostname} dev eth0`, etc but nothing seems to be working.

```
ip route

default via 71.182.224.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 71.182.224.241 metric 100
10.10.57.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.57.1
71.182.224.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 71.182.224.241 metric 100
```

Based on the article I was directed to I now have IP forwarding (routing) enabled on the Linux server too:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

But client machines still can't access the Internet through the Linux server. They can ping interface eth0 and eth1 on the Linux server but they can't ping beyond. Based on my experience with Cisco routers there needs to be a route something like:

```
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [1/0] via 71.182. 224.241, outside
```

I know how to do this on Cisco routers but I'm stumped with Linux. Unfortunately I have never used a Linux server as a router so I don't know what the proper routing table would look like. But I must be missing something that is preventing the client workstations from getting out to the Internet through the Linux server.

Can anybody help me with the proper command line syntax for this?

Comment: Are you sure you're not already getting a default route set by DHCP? Please provide your routing table

Comment: In addition, the linux box needs to forward packets between interfaces. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux

Comment: I suspect you've got a default route off `eth1` as well as `eth0`, and it's a matter of _removing_ the invalid route rather than adding one

Comment: The goal of this question is: have clients use Internet. But the question asked is of a much more limited scope. Solving the question (if there is something to solve) will likely not be enough to solve "the Goal": having a client attempt to use Internet to verify the default route was added will likely fail if other things are not also done. Topics involved: DHCP client (ISP side), DHCP *server* (clients side), IP forwarding, NAT.

Comment: "_Based on my experience with Cisco routers there needs to be a route something like {a default route}_". There is one already. Look at the first line of the routing table from `ip route`. What you're probably missing is the advertisement of a default route through DHCP to your internal clients via this server. And then a NAT firewall rule to masquerade those clients onto your single public IP address. This is all well documented in articles such as (the fictionally named) "How do I make my Linux server a firewall/router?"

Comment: So I guess the missing part is "NAT".

Comment: There's also [Understanding ip route output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/564273/100397)

Comment: Correct NAT was the missing part after enabling IP forwarding. I found documentation that shows how to set up NAT in Linux. Works great now as a router.

Answer (score 2):

Modern `ip route` command:

```
ip route add default via <gateway IP>
```

Legacy `route` command:

```
route add default gw <gateway IP>
```

With both commands, you can optionally add `dev <network device name>` to the end if necessary.

Comment: I couldn't use an IP address because it's DHCP assigned and changes but that wasn't the problem after all. I had to enabled IP forwarding (us Cisco people call it routing) then I had to enable NAT. Works great now, client machines have Internet access through the Linux box just like it was a router.